# asyncTimeout could not be use

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

@WebServlet(asyncSupported=true, asyncTimeout=5000)

in the about statement the asyncTimeout parameter gives error.

**Error:**
    WeatherServlet.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
    asyncTimeout = 3000

Can i use asyncTimeout as given in the about statement? or i can't use the parameter asyncTimeout in annotation @WebServlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`@WebServlet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation does not have an `asyncTimeout` element. I'm not sure what you mean by *about statement*, but you can't use it in the annotation.